# SSH over WAN through reverse proxy to LAN git server

Tags: ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy, git, gitlab

We have an URL to our external IP to our gateway that connects to a CentOS nginx reverse proxy behind which sits our CentOS6 Gitlab server on the company LAN

Through this we currently have http access to the Gitlab server. I would like to add SSH access to the equation. Unfortunately I am a coder and pretty much noob to servers, linux and, for the most part, SSH.

Is there a recommended method to achieve what I need while maintaining a reasonable level of security of the company's network (possibly restricting SSH connections to git only)?
How can I achieve this? Preferably with minimal setup at connection time which will be from MS Windows PCs

PS: I did look at some other questions here that seemed to be attempting something similar but my knowledge was too small and they were just different enough that I didn't understand how to adapt them to this situation.

EDIT: Network diagram added below. The router is just a home router at the moment. The gateway runs the firewall and forwards ports to the nginx.

[image: Network diagram]

Comment: What is the gateway device?  Could you add a network diagram to the question?

Comment: @MadHatter Added a diagram, does that provide enough info?

Comment: No.  It shows no IP information, so we have no idea if (eg) Zentyal to Gitlab is a routed transaction, or merely switched.  We nee to see the LAN logical layout.

Comment: do you have LAN users? or does anyone pass through your Router/GW reaching Gitlab? In the latter case, setting up some port forwarding on either your Router or Gateway, pointing to your Gitlab server directly, *could* be a solution. Otherwise: does LAN client access your Gitlab directly, or via reverse proxy?